WYSYWIG editor, cannot upload images. (Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom)
I cannot upload images with the WYSIWYG editor. When I open the image upload dialog. The folder names are not loaded correct. See image below. When I try to add an image, nothing happens. I think there is something going wrong with JS.
When I open the browser console I see the following erros.

Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom (loader_old.js:205)
No template was found by selector: null (template.js:52)

Not sure what the exact problem is and how to solve it.

